# Why does this result happen

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
playerlevel = 1
playerattack = 10
playerhealth = 100
playerexp = 0

print (playerlevel)
answer = input('have you played before? yes or no: ')
if answer == 'yes':
    level = input('what was your level: ')
    playerlevel *= level
    playerattack *= level
playerhealth *= level
else:
    pass

print ("player level: %s" % playerlevel)
print ("player health: %s" % playerhealth)
print ("player attack: %s" % playerattack)
print ("player exp: %s" % playerexp)
```

when i run this program it runs player level fine if level is 2 it prints 2 but the others it prints -> 2222222222222222222222222222222 for each. for exp its 0

Comment: playerhealth isn't indented properly...

Comment: There is an indention error just before the else command

Comment: Presumably the indentation error is just a transcription mistake from writing this question. Otherwise, he wouldn't be seeing any output at all rather than a bunch of twos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
level = input('what was your level: ')
```

`input` returns a string*. When you multiply a string by an integer, you get the string repeated that many times. For example, `"2" * 3` is `"222"`.

If you want actual numerical multiplication, convert level to an integer before using it.

```
level = int(input('what was your level: '))
```

<sub>*Applicable only in Python 3.X. `input` can return other types in 2.7 and below, but you should use `raw_input` instead in those versions.</sub>